# Meteor.js possible with Cassandra instead of MongDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, cassandra

I'm at the start of a project to create a customer support system. For this system I've looked at [Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/), which looks very interesting. The thing is that we want to build the rest of our system using [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

So my question is as follows; can meteor.js also be used with Cassandra instead of [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)? Are there any ready pieces of code to do this, or would we need to write a substantial amount of compatibility code ourselves?

Comment: This is not a question about recommended tools, but rather about compatibility between two specific technologies. As such it doesn't fall under the 'off-topic' clause, and imho shouldn't be closed. It's a valid and pretty important question.

Comment: Im sure it would be possible to use Meteor with any type of database you would like if your willing to put in the effort to make it work.

Comment: Yup, Massive fail, find a Q that everybody's interested in... Close it.

Comment: Voted to leave closed since I consider this Too Broad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any database you want with Meteor, but you'll lose three of the [seven key benefits](http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples) of the framework:

> Database Everywhere. Use the same transparent API to access your
>   database from the client or the server.
>
> Latency Compensation. On the client, use prefetching and model
>   simulation to make it look like you have a zero-latency connection to
>   the database.
>
> Full Stack Reactivity. Make realtime the default. All layers, from
>   database to template, should make an event-driven interface available.

I use Redis and Postgres with Meteor, in addition to MongoDB. I use [Meteor Methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) to expose functions on the client to create, read, update and delete records in other databases.

Official support for Redis and other databases is on the [Meteor roadmap](http://roadmap.meteor.com), currently targeted for version 1.1. Meteor is currently at version 0.7.0.1, so that's probably not going to happen soon.

If you want to integrate another datastore like Cassandra more tightly with Meteor, you would probably start with Meteor's [mongo-livedata](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/mongo-livedata) module.

Comment: I like this answer for it's completeness in explaining the integration and other methods that can be used to integrate external services. Well done.

Comment: Thanks, @Mb.Well Explained..
Here is a sample repo of meteor and cassandra connection using Meteor Methods to expose functions on the client to create, read, update and delete records in other databases.
https://github.com/sarat9/meteor-cassandraa

Comment: I guess for latency compensation you would also need to write a "minicassandra" for the client side?

Answer (score 2):

There have been a few attempts to use Meteor with other DBs, see [meteor-sql](https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql) for the most interesting I know of. Generally, it shouldn't be difficult to create a wrapper for your DB that covers querying and takes care of reactivity. It's a large bit of work, but fairly easy one.

The difficulty rises significantly when you also want to use your DB for user accounts. Meteor account system uses Mongo heavily, and is blends with the rest of the platform so much that it would be quite difficult to replace it. So you'd need a workaround: either low-level wrapper that would convert Mongo queries to Cassandra queries, or dual DB (Mongo for users, Cassandra for data), or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is asking opinion rather than any real question so I would expect your question to go away as being **very** off-topic.

If you had **really** looked at [Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/) then you would be aware that aside from the server side implementation, there is a good deal of work done on the client side code to *emulate* the server side interaction with MongoDB in order to keep both client and server patterns under a familiar model for the programmer. And that it's ambitious and far from perfect, but a pretty good show.

That kind of shoots, "*I want to use Cassandra as a back-end*" in the foot.

All said, feel free to **fork** and create your own Cassandra version of Meteor. Really, give it a go, and maybe you'll get some traction from others who are interested.