# Is it possible to run Meteor with a database besides MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

Meteor is configured to work out of the box with a MongoDB server.  While it doesn't seem to officially support other databases, has anyone gotten Meteor to work with a NoSQL database other than MongoDB?  If so, can you share your methods on doing so?

Comment: Support for other databases is on the [Meteor roadmap](https://trello.com/c/6ugalZMG/54-additional-database-support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been asked several times, including a few hours ago: [Meteor.js possible with Cassandra instead of MongDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679103/meteor-js-possible-with-cassandra-instead-of-mongdb)

Generally, it **is** possible, but be prepared to rewrite a few core packages if you want to retain all the functionality Meteor provides.